# Two solutions for balancing a chemical equation?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

$$\ce{6H2O2 + 2N2H4 → 2N2 + 10H2O + O2}$$

$$\ce{4H2O2 + N2H4 → N2 +6H2O + O2}$$

Which equation from above is correctly balanced? They all seem to be balanced but which one is correct?

Comment: @jimchmst The first equation was taken from the official Worked Solutions Chemistry HL - Catrin Brown and Mike Ford - Second Edition - Pearson 2014 Chapter 1 Exercise 3 (d). Do you think this was a mistake or was there an underlying implication? After reading Maurice's response, I thought this equation should not be dealt in an holistic manner as one can just simply multiply one of the separate equation by a random constant and get lots of solutions to balance this equation. Plus, H2O2 decomposes on its own right?

Comment: They are independent reactions with no stoichiometric relation and it is incorrect to add the equations as if they were. If both reactions are concurrent the products must be analysed to determine the extent of each. Possible exceptions to this are consecutive where a product reacts further.  Text books are rife with errors misconceptions and just opinions. This may be just my opinion that a chemical equation must be stoichiometrically correct, I do have the Law of conservation of mass and work of many chemists to back me up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All your equations are correctly written. But look !

The simplest equation would be $\ce{N2H4 + 2 H2O2 -> N2 + 4 H2O}$. But plenty of other acceptable equations can be obtained by adding an arbitrary number of times the following decomposition of $\ce{H2O2}$ : $\ce{2 H2O2 -> 2 H2O + O2}$.

For example, your first equation has been obtained in doubling my simplest equation and adding once the decomposition of $\ce{H2O2}$

Your second equation is obtained by adding my simplest equation plus once the decomposition of $\ce{H2O2}$

Comment: Neither equation is correct They do not describe a possible chemical reaction!

Comment: I took too long to edit! neither equation is correct. They do not describe a possible or reasonable chemical reaction! You do point out that the equations are the result of adding two equations that are not related stoichiometrically but must also carry thru and state that this is not a legal procedure even tho it is encountered frequently, and usually improperly, when dealing with consecutive or concurrent reactions.

Comment: @jimchmst  agreed with your comment of neither equation is correct. I also received $\ce{N2H4 + 2H2O2 -> N2 + 4H2O}$ as the correct answer based on tabulated Standard Reduction Potentials of $\ce{N2H4}$ and $\ce{H2O2}$ at $\pu{25 °C}$.